# PHP Simple html Dom can't read (br/) newline

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm learning to use the parser, simple html dom.

Sample code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<div class="column-2"><h1>Hey </h1><p>Gold Bar</p><p>Where are you?<br/>I am here<br/></p>');
foreach($html->find('p') as $br){
    $value[]=$br->outertext;
 }
echo $value[1];
?>
```

Result :

```
Where are you?
I am here
```

What if I want results from that's $html:

```
Where are you?
```

or

```
I am here
```

Comment: You need to add more information. You question is extreme vague. You also have two br. You have Breaks ,and your Variables that are '`br` please reform your question. Also add a space `<BR /> or </br>

Comment: Also look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to split the string further to get the string before or after the `<br/>` by using `explode()`http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html('<div class="column-2"><h1>Hey </h1><p>Gold Bar</p><p>Where are you?<br/>I am here<br/></p>');
foreach($html->find('p') as $br){
    $value[]=explode("<br/>", $br->outertext);
}
echo $value[1][0];
```